# Searching for an object from a list based on one or more criteria

Tags: java

I need to write a method in java so as to search for a object from a list of objects.The problem lies in the criteria for the search. I may need to search for object based on one criterion or a combination of multiple criteria, which will be decided at run time.How do I go ahead with it?

Comment: Loop through all the objects in the list, and check if the object matches the criteria.

Comment: I am aware of iterating through the list.However this may not serve purpose as the criteria used for searching will be dynamic.Search may depend on comparing just one data member or multiple,including all combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Reflection, take the below code as hint:-

```
for(ObjectToBeSearched bean:objectList){
    Field field = bean.getClass().getDeclaredField("searchKey");
    String searchKeyVal=field.get(bean);
    if(criteria.equals(searchKeyVal)){
    System.out.println("Object found!!!");
    }
    }
```

Approach should be:- Pass a HashMap where key will be object attribute name and value will be its value which need to be searched.
1) Now using the Map keys you can get the java.lang.reflect.Field.
2) Get the value of Field value using reflection.
3) Now compare it with the value in HashMap stored corresponding to the respective key.

The Map passed to the method can be absolutely dynamic.

Comment: I think reflection is way overkill here. Just make a getter function and compare its result with the criteria you want

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you have given so far, it is not clear who is creating the search criteria. If you have control over various criterion you could use Java 8 filter to apply a Predicate on the list and get what you want.

```
public List<String> find(Predicate<Employee> predicate) {
return employeeList.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

There's a nice article [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/04/04/how-to-use-predicate-in-java-8/) on how to leverage Predicates.